# C++ : Passing two dimensional array to extern NASM assebler function

Tags: c++, arrays, nasm

I am trying to pass a two dimensional char array from my C++ code to a NASM assembler extern function. I have no problems with passing simple arrays in this situation or two dimensional arrays to normal functions.

This is how I define the extern function:
`extern "C" void function(char[][]);`

My char array is defined like this:
`char A[n][m];`

But when I try to call the function:
`function(A);`

The compilation fails saying:

> candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char [n][m]' to 'int'

I just can't handle these `extern` function parameters...
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I got `error: multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first`, try `extern "C" void function(char[][m]);` (assuming that `m` is a compile time value).

Comment: Unfortunately the dimension of the array is unknown and I have to retrieve it from a file in the 'main' :/.

Comment: So the signature should be something like `function(char**, int size)` (assuming an array of c-string) or `function(char**, int size1, int size2)`. and you should have `char* A[n]`.